# Sending and Receiving Right Single Quotation Mark in Core Data

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-data, encoding

All I get back is /2019 and I need to pass the exact same data to the server back for a concurrency management system that I have appled. I am getting errors. How do I manage this text encoding?

Comment: can you post your errors and how you're sending it?

Comment: It's not clear what you are doing, or what problem you are having. Try adding more detail and maybe someone will be able to answer.